# Rendering an image in React from this.props

Tags: reactjs

I have an react application, that I created with Create-React-App. My objective is when a user clicks on an image, the image changes. So, I want the image to come from the props.

For some reason, this code does not work.

```
<img alt="mug shot" src={this.props.photo} />
```

However, this works

```
<img alt="mug shot" src={require('../../Assets/Photos/Four.png')}/>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are bundling your app using Webpack. Probably, you might be using a file-loader/url-loader to process the image. So, when you require something that ends with image file extension, webpack runs the contents of that file through this loader. For more information, check https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/images/

Comment: In your case, since you want to get image source from props, you can simply do ``<img alt="mug shot" src={require(`${this.props.photo}`)}/>``

Comment: Can you show what is there in your this.props.photo?

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    img:'https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg'
  }

  this.changeImg = this.changeImg.bind(this);
}

changeImg() {
  this.setState({
    img:'http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg'
  })
}

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ImageChande change={this.changeImg} src={this.state.img} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class ImageChande extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <img onClick={this.props.change} alt="something" src={this.props.src} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```